# Proof or counterexample related topology of metric spaces

Tags: general-topology

Let $(E,m)$ be a metric space with the topology induced by the metric. I want to prove or disprove this

If no open ball is contractible then $E$ has caridinality as much countable and all its points all point of accumulation.

Answer (score 0):

As a simple counterexample, let $E=\,\mathbb{R}{\setminus}\mathbb{Q}$, with the metric inherited from $\mathbb{R}$.

Then $E$ is uncountable, and no open ball is contractible.

Comment: Maybe I wrote bad the question, but this was the example I had in my mind. It's a example, not a counterexample of my question. It satisfies the hypothesis (no open ball is contractible) and the tesis (is a discrete space and all its point are point of accumulation).

Comment: @Rafael Gonzalez Lopez: The metric is not the discrete metric. What's your definition of a "discrete space"?

Comment: Sorry, I forogot check the usually definition. I changed the post.